# How do I push serveral id's from one table to another in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a booking system using sequelize, and I have to seperate tables.
One for Rooms and one for Hotel

What I want to do, is basically to push the ID of the room into the hotel table column called rooms.

It should be able to hold more than one id. Ergo an array. I am using myql which means I have define the rooms column as json as I understand it.

I can push only one id but that as I said is not enough.

My room model and controller looks like this

```
const Room = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const Room = sequelize.define("rooms", {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    maxPeople: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    desc: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    roomNumbers: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  });
  return Room;
};
export default Room;


export const createRoom = async (req, res, next) => {
  const hotelId = req.params.hotelid;
  const newRoom = new Room({
    title: req.body.title,
    price: req.body.price,
    maxPeople: req.body.maxPeople,
    desc: req.body.desc,
    roomNumbers: {
      number: req.body.roomNumbers.number,
      unavailableDates: [req.body.roomNumbers.unavailableDates],
    },
  });

  try {
    const savedRoom = await newRoom.save();
    try {
      await Hotel.findOne({
        where: {
          id: hotelId,
        },
      }).then((Hotel) => {
        Hotel.update({
          rooms: savedRoom.id,
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
    res.status(200).json(savedRoom);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

As you can see it pushes the savedRoom id but only the single one.

My Hotel model looks like this:

```
const Hotel = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const Hotel = sequelize.define("hotels", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    country: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    city: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    distance: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    photos: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    desc: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    rating: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(11, 10),
      min: 0,
      max: 9,
    },
    rooms: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    cheapestPrice: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(11, 10),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    featured: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      default: false,
    },
  });
  return Hotel;
};

export default Hotel;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Hotel model, the rooms field is defined as DataTypes.JSON. If you want to store an array of room IDs in this field, you can change the data type to DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER).

```js
    rooms: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER), // Assuming your room IDs are integers
      allowNull: true,
    }
```

In case you are using phpMyAdmin and Mysql, you will need to handle the serialization and deserialization (JSON to JavaScript object conversion) yourself. Sequelize automatically handles these operations for regular data types, but for JSON, you may need to perform additional steps. Try something like this,

```js
    rooms: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: true,
      get() {
        const rawValue = this.getDataValue("rooms");
        return rawValue ? JSON.parse(rawValue) : [];
      },
      set(value) {
        this.setDataValue("rooms", value ? JSON.stringify(value) : null);
      },
    }
```

Also you need to make sure you append the new room ID to the existing array of room IDs.

```js
export const createRoom = async (req, res, next) => {
   ...
  try {
    const savedRoom = await newRoom.save();

    const hotel = await Hotel.findOne({
    where: {
        id: hotelId,
    },
    });

    // retrieve existing room IDs or initialize an empty array if it doesn't exist yet
    const existingRoomIds = hotel.rooms || [];

    // add the new room ID to the array
    existingRoomIds.push(savedRoom.id);

    // call update method on the hotel instance with the new array of room IDs
    await hotel.update({
    rooms: existingRoomIds,
    });

    res.status(200).json(savedRoom);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: This also only adds a single room as [1] in the database column.

Comment: Yes. It does not add the new id to the array - it just update with the new room id :-/

Comment: I've added my Hotel model.

Comment: If it try to have that syntax for rooms in hotel model, I get an sql error:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[]"

Note I am using phpMyAdmin and Mysql - which is why I saved it as json in the first place because it doesnt support ARRAY.

Comment: I have updated the answer. phpMyAdmin was a vital part that you forgot to mention in your question. Try adding it in your question tags to gain attention from experts.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot - I will keep your comment in mind as regards to posting questions!